# updating node to 8.1.4 fails heroku build

Tags: node.js, heroku

I updated node v7.2.1 to v8.1.4. I got exceptions saying "Cannot find module 'async' and 'moment' after updating so I install them using npm install command (as suggested by stackoverflow thread".)
I tested the application everything seems working on my localhost but when i deployed it to Heroku it cause build failed with this error message.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  v8.1.4
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version v8.1.4 via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing node 8.1.4...
       Using default npm version: 5.0.3
-----> Restoring cache
       Skipping cache restore (new-signature)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)

       > lwip@0.0.9 install /tmp/build_b8b26cc33675c474632f5536a0d0ddaf/RugCoPro-rugcopro-d2ada6e26415ce13c992c071360307b40214a4bc/node_modules/lwip
       > node-gyp rebuild

       make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_b8b26cc33675c474632f5536a0d0ddaf/RugCoPro-rugcopro-d2ada6e26415ce13c992c071360307b40214a4bc/node_modules/lwip/build'
       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/init.o
       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/util.o
       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/buffer_worker.o
       ../src/decoder/buffer_worker.cpp: In constructor ‘DecodeBufferWorker::DecodeBufferWorker(Nan::Callback*, v8::Local<v8::Object>&, buf_dec_f_t)’:
       ../src/decoder/buffer_worker.cpp:8:58: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
       _height(0), _channels(0), _trans(false), _metadata("") {
       ^
       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/jpeg_decoder.o
       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/png_decoder.o
       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/gif_decoder.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jmemnobs.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jcomapi.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdapimin.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdapistd.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdatadst.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdatasrc.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdcoefct.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdcolor.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jddctmgr.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdhuff.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdinput.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdmainct.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdmarker.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdmaster.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdpostct.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdsample.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jerror.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jfdctflt.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jfdctfst.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jfdctint.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jidctflt.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jidctfst.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jidctint.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jutils.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jmemmgr.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdarith.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jdmerge.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jaricom.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jquant1.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/jpeg/jquant2.o
       CC(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/png/png.o
       In file included from ../src/lib/png/png.c:14:0:
       ../src/lib/png/pngpriv.h:805:4: error: #error ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM "-I (include path) error: see the notes in pngpriv.h"
       #  error ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM     ^
       make: *** [Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/png/png.o] Error 1
       make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_b8b26cc33675c474632f5536a0d0ddaf/RugCoPro-rugcopro-d2ada6e26415ce13c992c071360307b40214a4bc/node_modules/lwip/build'
       gyp ERR! build error
       gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_b8b26cc33675c474632f5536a0d0ddaf/RugCoPro-rugcopro-d2ada6e26415ce13c992c071360307b40214a4bc/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
       gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
       gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)
       gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-123-generic
       gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_b8b26cc33675c474632f5536a0d0ddaf/RugCoPro-rugcopro-d2ada6e26415ce13c992c071360307b40214a4bc/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_b8b26cc33675c474632f5536a0d0ddaf/RugCoPro-rugcopro-d2ada6e26415ce13c992c071360307b40214a4bc/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
       gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_b8b26cc33675c474632f5536a0d0ddaf/RugCoPro-rugcopro-d2ada6e26415ce13c992c071360307b40214a4bc/node_modules/lwip
       gyp ERR! node -v v8.1.4
       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
       gyp ERR! not ok
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! lwip@0.0.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR!
       npm ERR! Failed at the lwip@0.0.9 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-07-13T16_28_01_508Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku
         !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.  !     Push failed
```

I am new in it so could anyone let me know what could be the issue?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

From the build log it looks like a problem with installing `lwip` package,. This is a know issue documented on [Github](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip/issues/297).

Looks like there is no official solution yet, but there are many workarounds proposed. One is to use patched `lwip` package containing updated `libpng` and `zlib` dependencies. In your package.json you need to put

```
"lwip": "https://github.com/Pajk/lwip#development"
```

You should check the discussion on Github, maybe other workaround will work for you.

Comment: npm install skip lwip when i use a url.